# Does this code contain a hidden bug?

Tags: c++, mingw, setjmp

The following code :

- Runs fine when compiled with gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5/32bits)
- Runs fine when compiled with MSVC10 (Win7/32bits)
- Crashes when running with gcc version 4.5.2 (MinGW on Win7/32bits)

**main.cpp** :

```
# include <iostream>
# include <csetjmp>
# include <stdexcept>

using namespace std ;

void do_work(jmp_buf context)
{
    try
    {
        throw runtime_error("Ouch !") ;
    }
    catch(exception & e)
    {
    }

    longjmp(context, -1) ;                        //BP1
}

int main(int, char *[])
{
    jmp_buf context ;

    try
    {
        if( setjmp(context) != 0 )
        {
            throw runtime_error("Oops !") ;       //BP2
        }

        do_work(context) ;
    }
    catch(exception & e)
    {
        cout << "Caught an exception saying : " << e.what() << endl ;
    }
}
```

I tried debugging it but the program behaves strangely. Sometimes I could get past the first breakpoint (BP1), then crash at BP2, and sometimes control never reachs BP1, like if the program is stuck in an infinite loop. I cannot say more with my debugging skills.

This code is the minimal I could get that exhibits the strange behavior with MinGW 4.5. I also noticed that :

- If I replace the `do_work` function call by its content, the program runs fine.
- If I remove the `try{ ... } catch(...){ }` block inside `do_work`, the program runs fine.
- Optimization flags have no effect (always crashing).

I'm aware of the `setjmp/longjmp` issues in C++ code, but I'm forced to use it to interface with some legacy C code.

My question :

- Is this a faulty/buggy/erroneous code ? Or is MinGW 4.5 mishandling the code ? (It is harsh and presumptuous to blame the tool, but I suspect some settings in it).

Thanks for any advice.

<sub>Please retag if necessary.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The longjmp(3) man page on Unix says:

> The longjmp() routines may not be called after the routine which
>   called the setjmp() routines returns

I think it explains explains your concern that "*sometimes control never reachs BP1*".
I don't think "*runs fine*" is reliable judgement. I'd rather expect it randomly runs fine and generally is messing up with stack.

There are a few clear recommendations that should be taken into account while working mixing longjmp/setjmp with C++ exceptions in order to avoid crashes and undefined behaviour:

- Do not use setjmp/longjmp in C++ programs.
- If you use setjmp/longjmp functions in program where exceptions can occur, you are safe as long as they do not interact.
- Never longjmp in or out of try clause and catch clause.
- Never longjmp over point of initialization of automatic objects.
- Never longjmp pasy point of destruction automatic objects, especially if destructor is non-trivial.
- Never throw from signal handler.
- Never invoke longjmp from nested signal handler.
- Behaviour of longjmp from location X to location Y stays predictable and valid as long as if exception thrown at X and caught at X would have the same effect.
- If you mix setjmp/longjmp with exceptions, do not expect portability.
- Instead, refer to relevant details in documentation compiler you are using. For example, if you use Visual C++, read [Use setjmp/longjmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2ez4as.aspx)

The question mentions dealing with legacy C code in programs written in C++. There has been an interesting discussion on sjlj issues in jpeg library during review of one of Boost libraries. The discussion was long but here is [essence with recommended options](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/201425).

Comment: `main()` hasn't returned at the time of the `longjmp()`

Comment: Thanks ! But apart from point #1, I don't see where I missed the point (no pun intended).

Comment: @overcoder Yes, that's correct. I wanted to cover some background information in my answer. Regarding MinGW, are you sure you're using  MinGW with longjmp exceptions enabled? Run g++ -v to check it. I'm not MinGW user, but AFAIK MinGW distinguishes builds of C++ EH vs setjmp/longjmp. Note, MinGW-ready libraries like pthread offer separate builds for MingW (e.g. pthreadGCE.dll for C++ EH and pthreadGC.dll for sjlj EH). Simply these two gases don't mix.

Comment: @mloskot: Let me put it in other words : If I use a C lib that calls `setjmp/longjmp` in a C++ program, and If a wrap the whole `main` in a try-catch block, should I expect an undefined behavior ?

Comment: @mloskot: For me, `gcc -v` shows the `--enable-sjlj-exceptions` flag.

Comment: @overcoder I'd say that won't make you safe, I'm afraid. See my update with links to relevant discussion in Boost mailing list.

Comment: @overcoder Regarding `gcc -v` output. You seem to call setjmp() once and you seem to make sure that this is in a scope that contains all the possible calls to legacy C code. Hmm as fizzer pointed, perhaps compiler issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

C++ only makes one additional restriction on the use of `longjmp()`:

*If any automatic objects would be destroyed by a thrown exception transferring control to another (destination) point in the program, then a call to longjmp(jbuf, val) at the throw   point that transfers control to the same (destination) point has undefined behavior.* (18.7)

You seem to be aware of this, and your program doesn't do it.  I vote compiler defect.

Answer (score 0):

`longjmp` and `setjmp` are c functions, invoking them with C++ exception handling semantics and object destruction semantics is undefined behavior, which means its up to the implementation whether it works or not (your testing shows this, the SEH stack unwind semantics break things, depending on the type used, iirc your working ones are using dwarf2)

Comment: The C++ standard says in C.2.2(Standard C Library) : `The C++ Standard library provides 54 standard macros from the C library` this including `setjmp`. Moreover, no variable with automatic storage is left after calling `longjmp`. Also, as I noticed, the program works if I remove the `do_work` function call and replace it by the function content. If the setjmp/longjmp mechanism interferes with the C++ exceptions, things should never work.

Comment: @Necrolis: I have no frame-based objects that require correct destruction. And MSVC10 produces a correct program when meeting this requirement.

Comment: @overcoder How do you know it produces correct program. It can be correct by flux and actually produce unspecified or undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mloskot: I must confess that I'm relying on the tools. I cannot say with certitude that the code is correct, but, as far as I have tried, using `setjmp/longjump` in C++ with the necessary care never caused me a crash. So I'm asking : Is `setjmp/longjump` __usable with restrictions__ in C++ or is it an __undefined behavior__ ?

Comment: It's usable with a single restriction - don't skip destruction of automatic variables.  However, this restriction is extremely onerous to guarantee in practice.  It means you need to control the entire call chain between the setjmp and longjmp.  Avoid except in a few stylized examples.  My only use is in a few debugging macros.